# Fullcalendar how to add bottom border to calendar view except grid axis?

Tags: html, css, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Greetings I have problem. How get rid of border-bottom on calendar view(see image 1)?
This appears if using this css.

```
  .fc-scrollgrid-section-body > td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  }
```

[image: how error looks like]
What happens if you change `border-bottom` to `border` and sets to 0px then? Well calendar loses completely its bottom row(see image 2) It also did not showing in dayView and monthView.
[image: calendar without bottom line]

I tried add another custom styles to css(before that setting `.fc-scrollgrid-section-body > td` its border to 0px )
1)I know what (investigated in inspector) what days have `fc-day` style(see image 3)
[image: styles inside colum]

I added this styles to CSS but it also not working it completely not showing red border

```css
.fc .fc-timegrid-col{
  .fc-day{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  }
}
//and 
.fc-day{
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

another try

```css
.fc .fc-timegrid-cols{
  .fc-day,
  .fc-timegrid-col{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

using role tag to achieve same result

```css
[role=gridcell] {
  .fc-timegrid-col
  .fc-day {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

**What I want is to have day columns bottom line and grid axe do not have one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for dayGrid and WeekGrid not for month yet.

```css
.fc-day .fc-timegrid-col-frame {
    border-bottom: 1px solid $pitch-black-100;
}
```

UPDATE after 3+ hours of investigating
to add line for gridView month need to add this thing to styles

```css
.fc-daygrid-body {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $pitch-black-100;
}
```